# Crosswalk xwalkview html5 games sees slow (as lagged)than chrome web browser

Tags: android, html, webview, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I have this code in Oncreatedview in fragment

I choose xWalkView because in normal Webview the html5 sees (more lagged) and some images not update.

With xWalkView the lagged is less and images update fines ( but 3d games not are loading )

Some problems I have had with XwalkView are

1. games's music continues sounding after fragment is closed
2. all games are lagged (at comparison with chrome web browser where
   game are fluid)

The most importantes problem for me is the number 2. 
is there a way for game run fluid as chrome web browser?

```
WalkWebView=(XWalkView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webViewGame);

        xWalkWebView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);


xWalkWebView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(xWalkWebView) {


    @Override
    public void onPageLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url1) {
        super.onPageLoadStarted(view, url1);
        if (!urls.contains(url1)) {
            urls.add(url1);
        }
    }
});
```